# Why does my code not work?

Tags: infinite-loop

Why does the following code not work?

```
t=1;h=0.1;n=t/h+1;m=3;
W=Table[0,{n},{m+1}];
for[k=2,k<m+1,k++,
  f=Table[0,{n-2},{n-2}];
  f[[1,1]]=2-1/(1+10*h)+10*h*h*W[[2,k]];f[[1,2]]=-1+5*h;
  for[i=2,i<n-2,i++,
    f[[i,i]]=2+10*h*h*W[[i+1,k]];
    f[[i,i-1]]=-1-5*h;
    f[[i,i+1]]=-1+5*h;];
    f[[n-2,n-2]]=5*h+1+10*h*h*W[[n-1,k]];
  f[[n-2,n-3]]=-1-5*h;
  F=Table[0,{n-2}];
  for[i=1,i<n-1,i++,
    F[[i]]=
      -W[[i+2,k]]+2*W[[i+1,k]]-W[[i,k]]+
      5*h*(W[[i+2,k]-W[[i,k]])+
      5*h*h*W[[i+1,k]]*W[[i+1,k]];];

A=Linear Solve[f,-F];
for[i=2,i<n,i++,
   W[[i,k+1]]=W[[i,k+1]]+A[[i]]];
   W[[1,k+1]]=(W[[2,k+1]]+50*h)/(10*h+1);
   W[[n,k+1]]=W[[n-1,k+1]]];
```

Comment: 1) please format your code, add line breaks, and indent it for readability. 2) `For` should be uppercase 3) you should [avoid `For` loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951).

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. Use `For` not `for`; `LinearSolve` not `Linear Solve`; and there is a extra `]` in last For-loop.

Comment: `F` comes out as `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` because there is no code to populate `W`,

Comment: In the last inner For-loop, `(W[[i + 2, k] - W[[i, k]])` should be `(W[[i + 2, k]] - W[[i, k]])`

Answer (score 1):

This may be a partial answer. As I understand it your elaborate calculation of `f` can be replaced with:

```
t = 1;
h = 1/10;
n = t/h + 1;
f = 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> -1/2, Band[{1, 1}] -> 2, Band[{2, 1}] -> -3/2}, n - 2]
f[[1, 1]] = f[[-1, -1]] = 3/2;
f // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]